# What is the name of this movie?

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyborg

I found a gif-animation and by any means can't identify the movie it was taken from:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used [TinEye to look up the image](https://www.tineye.com/search/f8ebe0ab1e8ff991cd1c294b769c833382810720/), and found that it’s not from a science-fiction movie, but instead a commercial for the Motorola Droid X.

Comment: Vote to close then I reckon - mistaken identity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How I wished this was from a movie...

Answer (score 4):

It's not a sci-fi show, it's an advert for the new Verizon DroidX phone. The tv "spot" was created by animator [Kiel Figgins](http://www.3dfiggins.com/Broadcast/Droid/) and is available to view in HD on his website.